# ngOptions isn't showing any options in my select element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have ngOptions in one of my select elements connected to an array I made in the controller, and it's just not showing any values. I must be doing something stupid.

I know for sure that Angular is working, and the controller must be working because I use an expression related to an ngModel in the same div (using the same controller) and it works fine.

This is the relevant snippet of my html:

> `<div class="container" ng-app="tagQuestionnaireApp">
>       <div class="tagger" ng-controller="taggingController">
>           <form class="form-horizontal" name="tagForm" role="form">
>               <!-- Categorize Your Tag -->
>               <div class="form-group">
>                   <label class="sub" for="categorize">Categorize</label>
>                   <select class="form-control" id="categorize" ng-model="category" ng-options="cat.text in cat of categories"></select>
>               </div>
>           </form>
>       </div>
>   </div>`

This is my js file:

```
var tagQuestionnaireApp = angular.module('tagQuestionnaireApp', []);
   tagQuestionnaireApp.controller('taggingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.categories = [
        {text:'Humanities', topics:[{name:"Arts and Design",color:"#ff3d00"},
                                    {name:"History",color:"#ffc107"},
                                    {name:"Linguistics",color:"#ffab00"},
                                    {name:"Literature",color:"#ff7043"},
                                    {name:"Philosophy",color:"#dd2c00"},
                                    {name:"Theology",color:"#ff6f00"},
                                    {name:"Other Humanities",color:"#ff5722"}]},
        {text:'Social Sciences', topics:[{name:"Anthropology",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Archaeology",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Cultural/Ethnic/Area Studies",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Economics",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Gender/Sexuality Studies",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Geography",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Political Science",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Psychology",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Sociology",color:"#"},
                                    {name:"Other Social Sciences",color:"#"}]},
        {text:'Natural Sciences', topics:[{name:"Space sciences",color:"#00695c"},
                                          {name:"Earth sciences",color:"#8bc34a"},
                                          {name:"Biology",color:"#64dd17"},
                                          {name:"Chemistry",color:"#00bfa5"},
                                          {name:"Physics",color:"#009688"},
                                          {name:"Material Sciences",color:"#0a7e07"},
                                          {name:"Other Natural Sciences",color:"#259b24"}]},
        {text:'Engineering', topics:[{name:"Mechanical",color:"#"},
                                     {name:"Chemical",color:"#"},
                                     {name:"Civil",color:"#"},
                                     {name:"Electrical",color:"#"},
                                     {name:"Other Engineering",color:"#"}]},
        {text:'Formal Sciences', topics:[{name:"Applied Math",color:"#738ffe"},
                                         {name:"Computer Science",color:"#7986cb"},
                                         {name:"Logic",color:"#5c6bc0"},
                                         {name:"Pure Math",color:"#4e6cef"},
                                         {name:"Statistics",color:"#3949ab"},
                                         {name:"Systems Science",color:"#283593"},
                                         {name:"Other Formal Sciences",color:"#5677fc"}]},
        {text:'Other', topics:[{name:"Other",color:"#"}]}
    ];}]);
```

Comment: Should be `cat.text for cat in categories`

Comment: Wow, I had even checked it against the last time I used this. I knew it would be stupid. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
<select 
  class="form-control" 
  id="categorize" 
  ng-model="category" 
  ng-options="cat.text in cat of categories"
></select>
```

to:

```
<select 
  class="form-control" 
  id="categorize" 
  ng-model="category" 
  ng-options="cat.text for cat in categories"
></select>
```

and see if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: And I just saw that Anthony Chu posted a comment to this effect. If he posts it as an answer, accept his answer instead of mine.

Comment: No worries, you can mark this one as answer. I was too busy/lazy to create one.  :)